# Warning Creating default object from empty value in json

Tags: php, warnings

My json gives this warning (Creating default object from empty value)
in that lanes:

```
$json->error_mensaje->firstname->name = 'firstname';
$json->error_mensaje->firstname->msg = '';
```

my json object is inicialiced:

```
$json = new stdClass();
```

And I try this:

```
$json->error_mensaje->firstname=new stdClass();
$json->error_mensaje->firstname->name=new stdClass();
$json->error_mensaje->firstname->msg=new stdClass();
```

but doesnt work.

Error reporting in php.ini is:
    error_reporting(E_ALL)
I tried to change it but doesnt work.

Creating my error handler is not a solution because im using an external cms.

Thank you